# CSS selector - not under direct parent

Tags: css, less

I have a nested display and I'm trying to style all nested collection besides the first one

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="main-collection">
        <div class="collection">

            <!-- lots of code -->
            <div class="collection"></div>

            <!-- lots of code -->
            <div class="collection"></div>

            <!-- lots of code -->
            <div class="collection">

                <!-- lots of code -->
                <div class="collection"></div>

                <!-- lots of code -->
                <div class="collection"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I want all but the one directly under `main-collection`

I'm using `less`.

Comment: It would be simpler if you changed the HTML. In this case I'd simply drop the outer `<div class="collection">`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.main-collection > .collection .collection {
    /* your styles here */
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LFR3t/)

Select all `.collection` elements that are descendants of a `.collection` element that is it's self a DIRECT descendant (`>`) of `.main-collection`

Answer (score 2):

**try to this** in less css

```
.main-collection{
   >.collection{
    // here style
     >.collection{
        // here style
           >.collection{
              // here style
           }
       }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way to do this is to use [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child), although support is limited for older browsers. If you have control over your markup, have you considered using a class to identify the element you want to style differently, in particular?

Comment: The `:first` selector has better support. Change all `.collection` elements then change the first one back.

Answer (score 0):

Do the css for all of the elements first and then below that select only the first one and do your styles for it. The css below overrides the other stuff above. You can do it with `:nth-child(1)` or I guess `:first-child`or probably even `:first-of-type` and `:nth-of-type(1)`

```
.main-collection .collection {
    css for all of them
}

.main-collection .collection:nth-child(1) {
    this will only target the first one
}
```